# stellar_dotnet_sdk Streaming?

Tags: stream

I'm using the stellar_dotnet_sdk library. I would like to use the Streaming functionality to get Transactions.

I followed the examples in the SDK (Java version) and right after the .Cursor() there is a .Stream( function. The stellar_dotnet_sdk doesn't have this function.

Does anyone have a simple example how to accomplish Streaming using this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have stream in .NET too, you can find an example here https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk/blob/e10e87592feda9fe22383490a400e32105001e49/stellar-dotnet-sdk-console/Program.cs#L30

Let me know if that helps you.